# What is the meaning of this taweez (tawiz) writtings?

Tags: quran-translation, arabic-translation, tawiz

Yesterday inside my pillow I found triangular shaped object wrapped inside was some kind of note.  Below is a picture of it:

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw1l-Rr6IeVhS2ZXamxoVm1Cc3c]

My family and I are Orthodox Christians, this seems to me is something coming from the Islamic beliefs.  We are very confused how this got inside the pillow and most importantly can somebody tell me what to do with it, what the text says on it, and what the flower frames means? Recently I was in a accident that left me paralyzed; is there any relation to this message.  It sounds crazy, but I'm just saying.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. This paper is a copy oft Surat al-ma'oon one oft the last ten surahs of the Quran.

Comment: Here is a link where you can read the translation and interpretation of this chapter of the Holy Qur'an, https://www.al-islam.org/enlightening-commentary-light-holy-quran-vol-20/surah-maun-chapter-107               The flowers around are just for decoration.

Answer (score 2):

In the name of Allah, most gracious most merciful.

Welcome to Islam SE.

**What is this?**

This is a copy of alma'oon  سورة الماعون.  It's a sura (a chapter of Quran), the text of the surah in english and arabic [here](https://quran.com/107):

> Have you seen the one who denies the Recompense?  For that is the one who drives away the orphan And does not encourage the feeding of the poor. So woe to those who pray [But] who are heedless of their prayer - Those who make show [of their deeds] And withhold [simple] assistance.

A tafseer (interpretation) of the sura is [here](http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-Al-Maun).  There is other interpretations and translations; see this:
[Why are there different translations of the Quran?](http://%20https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/why-are-there-different-translations-of-the-quran?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**What does the flower frame mean?**

It's just some flowers used for decoration!  Not every mushaf (Quran book) has the same decoration, a lot of them without any frames; these are all just used for decoration. Some others used for make reading more clear, like circles with number of verses, and some other symbols.

**What to do with it?**

You can keep it.  The letter of the Prophet (peace be upon him) to Hercules contained a Quranic verse [here](http://www.cyberistan.org/islamic/letters.html).

From this scholars said that non-Muslims could keep Quranic verses, but please endeavour to respect it and keep it in a clean place, and try to don't put anything on it.

**If you don't want to keep it, how to dispose of it?**

Well the khalifah (king of muslims) othman r.a when he wanted to dispose of some qurans copies because of some reasons, he ordered to burn them, from this scholar said that you have to burn it. I read in a fatwa that you can also also shred it with a paper shredder.

**Is there any relation between this message and my accident?**

If you find this crazy and could not come to your pillow in a normal way, none can know the relation or the reason but you.  Try to read the translation of the verses and some interpretations.  If there is a message related to you life, you will incha'allah find it.

If there is no message or relation, take this chance to read more about Islam, feel free to ask here about anything.

May Allah guide us all.

> Allah guides to His light whom He wills. And Allah presents examples
>   for the people, and Allah is Knowing of all things
>
> [quran 24/35](https://quran.com/24/35)

Comment: For a sunni tafsir on the surah see [here](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1076&Itemid=163) and click "next" on the bottom of the site to go through the tafsir of it.

Comment: You should Not burn it. It's better to shredder it or cut it into little pieces so the words are not recognisable any more.

Comment: @Noor any references ?

Comment: I heard it several weeks ago in a lecture. Had s.th . to do that  fire is associated with hell, hellfire. I try to find a written reference.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, just to add while searching the pillow again there was a red cloth I guess in that was the note wrapped. I have read the interpretations of the text and I have great respect to religions, the words really confused me like someone is trying to target me as not a good person and send an anger on me. I dont know if the intensions are dark and going to the occult subject.

Comment: @ecipec sometimes quranic texts are used in Talismans to hurt people , but usually such verses are not used . and those Talismans are used to get a husband or hurt  enemies and such things . this note is absolutely not a Talisman . why ? because it's only a page of quran . no other Suspicious texts   ;!
 i can't understand how this came to your pillow !